# SWIG/C#: convert a std::vector<unsigned char> to byte[]

Tags: c#, c++, swig

How can I wrap all usages of a `std::vector<unsigned char>` in a C++ library with a `byte[]` in C# when using SWIG to generate the wrappers?

I'm handling mostly binary data in my library and would like to avoid using the `std_vector.i` templates provided by SWIG, which create an implementation of `IList<byte>` that has to go through the PInvoke layer for accessing / modifying each element.

I'd rather have the whole memory be copied to / from a native array whenever it gets passed in to or out of a method. Below are the typemaps I created for use in Java. How can this be done for C#?

```
%typemap(jni) std::vector<unsigned char> "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) std::vector<unsigned char> "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) std::vector<unsigned char> "byte[]"
%typemap(javain) std::vector<unsigned char> "$javainput"
%typemap(javaout) std::vector<unsigned char> { return $jnicall; }

%typemap(in) std::vector<unsigned char> (std::vector<unsigned char> vec) {
  if (!$input) {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "null array");
    return $null;
  }
  const jsize sz = jenv->GetArrayLength($input);
  jbyte* const jarr = jenv->GetByteArrayElements($input, 0);
  if (!jarr) return $null;
  vec.assign(jarr, jarr+sz);
  jenv->ReleaseByteArrayElements($input, jarr, JNI_ABORT);
  $1 = &vec;
}

%typemap(out) std::vector<unsigned char> {
  const jsize sz = $1.size();
  $result = jenv->NewByteArray(sz);
  jenv->SetByteArrayRegion($result, 0, sz, reinterpret_cast<signed char *>($1.data()));
}

%apply std::vector<unsigned char> { const std::vector<unsigned char> & };
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: A newer answer looks like it may be useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224415/convert-char-buffers-to-byte-arrays-when-using-swig-and-c-sharp