# Convert char* buffers to byte arrays when using SWIG and C#

Tags: c#, arrays, char, buffer, swig

I maintain a C++ SDK that now needs to be converted to other languages (specifically C# and Java). I am using SWIG to generate my wrapper code and successfully have completed the Java work. I now need to get C# working.

I have a C++ function (ignore the `Header` object in the function signature - I have that worked out already)

```cpp
int send(Header header, char *payload);
```

Furthermore, I have a `director` class in C++ that is as follows:

```cpp
class Callbacks {
public:
    virtual ~Callbacks() { }
    virtual void receive(Header header, char *payload) { }
};
```

Which allows me to create callbacks in my Java and C# code.

I need the following function signatures for `send` and `receive` in C#:

```cs
int send(Header header, byte[] payload);
```

and

```cs
void receive(Header header, byte[] payload);
```

Typemaps in SWIG seem to be the way to go so here was my attempt at typemapping for C#:

```
%module(directors="1") example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%feature("director") Callbacks;

%include "arrays_csharp.i"
CSHARP_ARRAYS(char, byte)
%typemap(imtype, inattributes="[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=2048, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.U1)]") char INPUT[] "byte[]"

%apply char INPUT[] {char *payload}

%include "example/include/example.h"
```

The results of that interface file gets my desired function signatures but my byte arrays are only size 1 and I only get the first item in my original char buffers. It seems as if SWIG interpreted the char* as a pointer to a char and therefore stuck the first element in my char* buffer into a byte array and called it good. But I would like to create a byte array of size 2048 (no payload will have a size greater than that) and fill that byte array from the char* buffer. If it makes any difference, my `Header` class object has the size of the char* buffer but I really could care less about that right now and stick with an overall size of 2048 bytes.

Thoughts or help would be appreciated!

@Flexo I have seen your other SWIG posts on StackOverflow and you seem to by my guy for helping me out. Fingers crossed you see this!

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem, and have just got it to work.

C++ as follows

// Access.h

```
class Access
{
    void foo(unsigned char *inputBytes, int nbytes);
};
```

Swig .i file is then as follows.  It appears to be important that the %apply appears *before* the %include of the code to be wrapped.  If it is after then nothing changes.

```
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%apply unsigned char INPUT[]  {unsigned char *inputBytes}  
%include "Access.h"
```

C# is then like this

```
byte[] data = ...
var access = new Access();
access.foo(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length);
```

With swig 3.0.2 I could not get this to work at all.  With swig 3.0.12 I was successful.

I have not yet needed an output array, but this method would at least work with a pre-allocated buffer in C#.

Comment: This works for me in SWIG 4.1.0 (current master). Note that the spelling of `unsigned char INPUT[]` is important! Changing it to `unsigned char DATA[]` did *not* work.

Comment: Actually your suggested solution and some other options are quite nicely explained in the SWIG C# documentation at https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_arrays